# How to convert his Python script into PHP

Tags: php, python, sockets

I've tried my best but I can't seem to get it. For a little backstory, I have a WIFI RGB LED Controller Receiver that controls some leds on my network.

I have a python script that successfully turns them on when executed. I'm trying to convert this python script to php but I have yet to be successful.

Python script:

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = '192.168.1.6' # IP of the controller
    port = 5577

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    s.send('EF0177'.decode('hex')) # connect
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.send('CC2333'.decode('hex')) # send command (turn on in this case)
    s.close() # disconnect

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Like I said, that python script works.

Here is my attempt at php:

```
//Connect socket to remote server
if(!socket_connect($sock , '192.168.1.6' , 5577))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Connection established <br>";

$message = 'EF0177';

 //Send the message to the server
if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Message send successfully <br>";

$message = 'CC2333';

//Send the message to the server
if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Message send successfully <br>";
```

I don't get any errors in my php script however it does not successfully turn on the leds, so clearly I am missing something.

Comment: this is not a code translation service

Comment: @Dagon understandable response, however I do not know where else to turn. It's not like I didn't try. I made a genuine attempt and need help with my php. If not on how to translate on how to send a value through a socket in php.

Comment: why do you want to do it in php? why not just do it in python since it works  there?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I don't know python however I am very familiar with php (minus sockets). Beyond that every other interface I have on my network is interfaced from php.

Comment: I intend to post a new answer but I think it's better to be a comment. I hardly do experiment with socket right away with hardware, basically first to check with socket helper/tester program locally. I suggest you take a look at [SocketTest](http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/) or just a simple python script as a server to do ping-pong and analyse on the data.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear your problem comes from these two lines:

```
'EF0177'.decode('hex')
'CC2333'.decode('hex')
```

The results of these expressions are binary data 3 bytes long - the integer data `[0xef, 0x01, 0x77]` for the first.

In your PHP, you're just sending the text (which is 6 bytes long).

Since you can just express them as strings with hex escape codes, you can just replace the two `$message =` lines in your PHP code with:

```
$message = '\xEF\x01\x77';
$message = '\xCC\x23\x33';
```

It's also possible that the server that you're sending to is expecting you to read the data in-between sends (with [`socket_recv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php)).

Comment: I tried those two values, it did not work. Before posting I also tried using bin2hex on my values, with no success. I will try the socket_recv now, good idea

Comment: Also ensure that when setting up your socket, that you are following the defaults for Python's socket (`AF_INET` and `SOCK_STREAM`).

Comment: Still I have yet to have success, I did notice that and changed my connect to if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET,  SOCK_STREAM, 0))) I am also looking into the difference between socket_write and socket_read

Comment: @Travis I know Python well but PHP little-to-none. Try to write the PHP with each line of the Python `Main` function with a group of PHP code. Ensure each line matches what the Python does. Also, are you positive that the Python code does work?

Comment: I am positive the python works, when I run the script from my server the leds turn on! My problem is I don't know python so it's hard to replicate it when I don't know what it's doing. Beyond that I don't know sockets at all so that makes it even more complicated

Comment: Here is the documentation for [str.decode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode) and [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html). Compare it with the documentation for PHP and ensure the exact same data is being sent over the sockets in both situations.